# If files exist in directory,move it powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am a PowerShell beginner
May I have a question,
Is there any PS script that can always detect files in a directory in the background,
If files exist in the directory, move it to another location.

I tried using .PS1 (Move-item cmdlet) on taskscheduler, but it can't be work

Can Powershell do that?

Comment: Possible duplication of question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50995954/check-if-file-exists-then-move-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google for `FileSystemWatcher` and `PowerShell`, FileSystemWatcher allows you to specify a directory to watch for changes and then act on those changes. Like if a new file is detected, you can move it.

It seems there are several examples of scripts doing this out there.